# Increase performance of TextBlock

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, xaml, data-binding

I have a page with a [textblock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(v=vs.110).aspx) element inside a [scrollviewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.110).aspx). The textblock is bound to a string which is appended with up to 800 lines. I noticed the performance of scrolling and binding updates is noticeably bad; 2 - 3 seconds.

How can I optimize this scheme while maintaining the same actions? (scrolling binding text)

```
<ScrollViewer Name="resultsScrollView"
              Grid.Row="1"
              IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
              CanContentScroll="True"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
              VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Results,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="#2f323b"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontFamily" Value="Roboto"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Have you tried not to use scrollViewer?

Comment: Just tried it now. Binding updates are definitely faster but I still need a way to scroll down :)

Comment: Several questions... Why are you using an inline `Style` to set properties of the `TextBlock` when you could set them directly? `TextBlock` is readonly, why are you setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` on the binding?

Comment: You may want to consider using individual `TextBlock`s inside an `ItemsControl` that is using a `ScrollViewer` as its container.   If you bind `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` to an `ObservsableCollection<string>` you will likely get better performance because of virtualization.  The only issue is that you won't get one "solid" block of text.  It will be organized in to individual lines.  Depending on what you are trying to do (logging?), this may actually be better for you.

Comment: Awesome that sounds like a plan. Feel free to make that the answer; ill set this as solved.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Just implemented now and it's as smooth as silk; Thank you!

Comment: Cool, I'll type something up for an answer when I get back to my computer.